# loop through classes after successful AJAX call within a sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I have a `sortable` call which allows me to change the order of songs I have listed by dragging them which is the working part. What I want to do is try and get a number in front of each title so that the user knows which is the first song and so on by using a label like `1.`

I am putting the code within the `success` callback from AJAX which basically just updated the `query` and changes the order in the DB which also works fine.

What I cant get to work is the loop `.each` within the `success` callback in AJAX. It does not seem to want to fire or even find the classes `.song-orders`

I have shown what it looks like before and what I want it to look like after.

**JQUERY**

```
$('.draggablePanelList').sortable({
    update: function(event, ui) {
        var wafilesid = $(this).find('.wafilesid').attr('id');
        var grouptype = [];
        $(this).find('.sortableid').each(function() {
            grouptype.push($(this).attr('id'));
        });
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "../includes/updatesetlists.php?",
            data:({grouptype: grouptype, wafilesid: wafilesid}),
            success: function(data) {
                count = 1;
                $(this).find('.song-orders').each(function() {
                    $(this).('.song-orders').prepend(count+'. ');
                    count++;
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
```

**HTML BEFORE**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled draggablePanelList" style="overflow:auto;">
    <div class="song-orders">Title Of Song 1</div>
    <div class="song-orders">Title Of Song 2</div>
    <div class="song-orders">Title Of Song 3</div>
    <div class="song-orders">Title Of Song 4</div>
    <div class="song-orders">Title Of Song 5</div>
</ul>
```

**HTML AFTER**

```
<ul class="list-unstyled draggablePanelList" style="overflow:auto;">
    <div class="song-orders">1. Title Of Song 1</div>
    <div class="song-orders">2. Title Of Song 2</div>
    <div class="song-orders">3. Title Of Song 3</div>
    <div class="song-orders">4. Title Of Song 4</div>
    <div class="song-orders">5. Title Of Song 5</div>
</ul>
```

Comment: what do you want to refer to by using `$(this)` in `$(this).find('.song-orders')` ?

Comment: I want to refer `.draggablePanelList` since that's the main container so it finds only the `.song-orders` within that particular container

Comment: do `console.log(event,ui)` and check if you can get a reference to your desired element using `ui.widget` or something in `event` object. Misunderstanding `$(this)` is the problem in your code

Comment: um that is not even remotely close to a duplicate of that question but whatever